# Change button / text on button after read less

Tags: html, jquery

READ MORE / READ LESS jQuery which I implemented on my HTML Bootstrap page, works BUT as a happy amateur I would like to change my blue text "Read More" to Black, after and if I read more. The page has many Read More sections.

```js
// This function will handle hidden and read more events
$(document).on("click", ".toggle-text-button", function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Read More") {
    var thisNow = document.getElementById('toggle-text-button')
    console.log("this is now =", thisNow);
    $(this).text("Read Less");
    // Use a jquery selector using the `.attr()` of the link
    $("#toggle-text-" + $(this).attr("toggle-text")).slideDown();
  } else {
    $(this).text("Read More");
    //   $(this).addClass("r-Less");
    // Use a jquery selector using the `.attr()` of the link
    console.log("SLIDE UP -- this is now =", $(this).attr("toggle-text"));
    var BackToo = ("#" + "toggle-text-" + $(this).attr("toggle-text") + "b");
    var BackCol = ("#" + "toggle-text-" + $(this).attr("toggle-text"));
    // offset = $(BackToo).offset().top - document.getElementById(BackToo).clientHeight;
    console.log("JUMP BACK =", BackToo)
    // $(".r-More").css("color", "black!important");
    //  $(this).css("color" , "black!important");
    $("#toggle-text-" + $(this).attr("toggle-text")).slideUp();
    // $(this).addClass("r-Less");
    //document.getElementById(BackToo).scrollIntoView();
    //  $(BackToo)[0].scrollIntoView();
    //   $('html,body').unbind().animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top-50},'slow');
    $("html, body").delay(1000).animate({
      scrollTop: $(BackToo).offset().top - 150
    }, 1000);
    // $(this).attr("toggle-text").css("color","blacl!important");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toggle-text-button item-link r-More" toggle-text="10">Read More<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

Comment: To be clear, the Color on the Read More, I like to change after that I have read more and click Read Less.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add at least two sets of html with links in a [mcve]

Comment: Being not skilled at all, can you please write me the line I need to use, pls

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69203046/295783)

Answer (score 1):

No need to script that

You can give the `a` an href and use :visited css

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.inspirothemes.com/polo/css/style.css" />

<style>
a.r-More:visited { color: black; }
</style>

<a href="#" class="toggle-text-button item-link r-More" toggle-text="10">Read More<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

Comment: Did add
a:visited { color: black!important; 
   }
Doesn't work, I am using Bootstrap 5 and Theam POLO

It for sure would work on a plain Bootstrap, but not in my case

Comment: Works for me above - see update

Comment: The <a href="#"....  can not be used, How to make the change color in the jQuere? I think that is the way to do it?

mplungjan I will try to learn how to ask and put working well as an example, thanks for your instructions...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing css of class .r-More? Doing it, you are going to change all buttons.

Try remove this:

```
$(".r-More").css("color", "black!important");
```

And add just:

```
$(this).css("color" , "#000"); // avoid to use !important
```

Now, you have to back to the original color (blue, maybe), when the user clicks at "Read Less":

```
$(this).css("color" , "blue");
```

If you want to change others css parameters, I suggest you use some class, like ".readMoreClass". Then, you just have to use:

```
$(this).addClass(".readMoreClass") // to add class
$(this).removeClass(".readMoreClass") // to remove class
```

Hope have help you!

Comment: Thanks, Rodrigo, I will try. The problem I have come to learn by using POLO is that it is very hard to add any CSS, their SCSS seems to override everything... I have some minimal experience and have used CSS extensively and got it to work, somewhat acceptable, but this is now a new experience with POLO. I am very thankful for your and other members help.

Comment: If it stills hard, try to create a new custom button, using an own div class. Then, if this works, you know that problem is your template.

Comment: Could NOt get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seems to be based on the strong Template from POLO, I was able to get it to work by adding a style directly on each ""Read More   ""

and then in jQuere i only needed to use: "" $(".toggle-text-button").css("color" , "red");""

As stated before I do not have knowledge of jquery, so the problem may have been that I did try to change the color on the wrong reference...

Thanks for your Tips